# Group Aggreggate Mongo Approved Posts By User

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have 3 tables

articles, pages & users

a user has several articles and one article belongs to a page and a specific page type. how to return the number of articles per pages type, per user?

Ex:

John

3 type A articles

5 type B articles

```
    {
        $match: {
            project_id      : ObjectId("5d9604074dc1e055a83520e9"),
            moderator_id    : {$ne: null},
            created: {
                $gt: ISODate("2020-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"),
                $lt: ISODate("2020-10-30T00:00:00-03:00")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from         : "pages",
            localField   : "page_id",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as           : "pages"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from         : "users",
            localField   : "moderator_id",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as           : "users"
        }
    }
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id  : "$moderator_id",
            data : {
                $first : {
                    name                : "$users.name",
                    blogCount           : { $sum    : { $cond : { if: { $eq : [ "$pages.type", "blog" ] },             then : 1, else : 0 } } },
                    subBlogCount        : { $sum    : { $cond : { if: { $eq : [ "$pages.type", "sub-blog" ] },         then : 1, else : 0 } } },
                    subBlogCourseCount  : { $sum    : { $cond : { if: { $eq : [ "$pages.type", "sub-blog-course" ] },  then : 1, else : 0 } } },  
                }
            },
            count   : {$sum:1}
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for the question, I hope it can help anyone else.

````
    {
        $match : {
            project_id      : ObjectId("5d9604074dc1e055a83520e9"),
            moderator_id    : {$ne: null},
            created: {
                $gt: ISODate("2020-09-01T00:00:00-03:00"),
                $lt: ISODate("2020-10-30T00:00:00-03:00")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from         : "pages",
            localField   : "page_id",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as           : "pages"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$pages"  
    },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from         : "users",
            localField   : "moderator_id",
            foreignField : "_id",
            as           : "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$users"
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id: 0,
            moderator_id    : "$moderator_id",
            name            : "$users.name",
            type            : "$pages.type",
            blog            : { $cond : { if: { $eq: ["$pages.type", "blog"] },             then: 1, else: 0 } },
            subBlog         : { $cond : { if: { $eq: ["$pages.type", "sub-blog"] },         then: 1, else: 0 } },
            subBlogCourse   : { $cond : { if: { $eq: ["$pages.type", "sub-blog-course"] },  then: 1, else: 0 } },   
        } 
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id                 : "$moderator_id",
            moderator_name      : { $first  : "$name" },
            blogCount           : { $sum    : "$blog" },
            subBlogCount        : { $sum    : "$subBlog" },
            subBlogCourseCount  : { $sum    : "subBlogCourse" }, 
        }
    }
])```
````